# Google's VRView (Web) Render unable to load texture from localhost

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, virtual-reality

For some reason Google's VRView (Web) Render is unable to load texture from localhost or some website (even if I use the same image).

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/build/vrview.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad)
function onVrViewLoad() {
  var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
    image: 'test.jpg',
    width: 960,
    height: 480
  });
}
</script>
<div id="vrview"></div>
</html>
```

Now if I replace test.jpg with https://c1.staticflickr.com/7/6074/6119051772_0179026c3c_b.jpg, it works. But if I replace test.jpg with https://i.stack.imgur.com/exQQb.jpg (same image), it wouldn't work.

Is VRView picky about the hosting server?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in the web developer console when loading the image fails? This can be an CORS issue. Also check the network tab with details to the request.

Are you testing on a local web server or is localhost a mental shortcut for loading a html file from the `file://` protocol? If so, this might not work because of sandboxing.

Comment: No, CORS is the first thing I checked and nothing showed up in the console. And no, I was running PHP, Node.js, and Python environments when I debug this and none of the environments worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe **VRView requires a URL** to work correctly, see [Hosting](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview).

Also, I noticed a 10KB file size difference between the two images on Flickr and Imgur. Could it be **Imgur stripped the Photo Sphere XMP metadata from your JPG?** The XMP metadata is required by VRView to render a flat equirectangular image as a spherical 360° panoramic.

Facebook 360 provides helpful Photoshop templates (with metadata) for post-editing at: https://facebook360.fb.com/360-photos/